# How MongoClient::save(...) might change the _id field of document parameter

Tags: vert.x, mongodb-java

I have a class `User` that embeds a `JsonObject` to represent the user's fields. This class looks like that:

```
class User {
  private JsonObject data;

  public User(...) { 
    data = new JsonObject();
    data.put("...", ...).put(..., ...);
  }

  public String getID() { return data.getString("_id"); }

  // more getters, setters

  // DB access methods
  public static userSave(MongoClient mc, User user){
    // some house keeping
    mc.save("users", user.jsonObject(), ar -> {
      if(ar.succeeded()) { ... } else { ... }
    });
  }


}
```

I've just spent more than half a day trying to figure out  why a call to `user.getID()` sometimes produced the following error: `ClassCastException: class io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject cannot be cast to class java.lang.CharSequence`. I narrowed down to the `userSave()` method and more specifically to `MongoClient::save()` which actually produces a side effect which transforms the `data._id` from something like

```
"_id" : "5ceb8ebb9790855fad9be2fc"
```

into something like

```
"_id" : { 
  "$oid" : "5ceb8ebb9790855fad9be2fc"
}
```

This is confirmed by the vertx documentation which states that "*This operation might change _id field of document parameter*". This actually is also true for other write methods like inserts.

I came with two solutions and few questions about doing the `save()` properly while keeping the `_id` field up to date.

**S1** One way to achieve that is to save a copy of the Json Object rather than the object itself, in other words : `mc.save("users", user.jsonObject().copy(), ar -> {...});`. This might be expensive on the long run.

**S2** An other way is to "remember" `_id` and then to reinsert it into the `data` object in the `if(ar.succeeded()) {data.put("_id", oidValue); ...}` section. But as we are asynchronous, I don't think that the interval between `save()` and the `data.put(...)` is atomic ?

**Q1**: Solution **S1** make the assumption that the ID doesn't change, i.e., the string `5ceb8ebb9790855fad9be2fc` will not change. Do we have a warranty about this ?

**Q2**: What is the right way to implement the `saveUser()` properly ?

**EDIT**: The configuration JSON object user for the creation of the `MongoClient` is as follows (in case there is something wrong) :

```
"main_pool" : {
        "pool_name"         : "mongodb",
        "host"              : "localhost",
        "port"              : 27017,
        "db_name"           : "appdb",
        "username"          : "xxxxxxxxx",
        "password"          : "xxxxxxxxx",
        "authSource"        : "admin",
        "maxPoolSize"       : 5,
        "minPoolSize"       : 1,
        "useObjectId"       : true,
        "connectTimeoutMS"  : 5000,
        "socketTimeoutMS"   : 5000,
        "serverSelectionTimeoutMS" : 5000
}
```

Comment: Can you try to configure your client with `useObjectId` set to `true`? This should force the client to persist identifier strings as objects but preserve the type. See https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/#_configuring_the_client

Comment: @tsegismont: this is already the case. I edited the question and added the configuration object that I pass to the MongoClient. Maybe there is something wrong in there...

Comment: Can you file an issue to the Vert.x Mongo Client repository?

Comment: Looks like it had been discussed for quite long time whether its a bug or not. It looks not so easy to fix. https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client/issues/39

Comment: Just to complete, here is the demonstator: https://gitlab.com/mszmurlo/vertx-mongo-issue-demo